# Наложение линии на 3d объект

Tags: javascript, css, 3d

У меня есть поверхность (`div`), которая трансформирована в `3d` (CSS), то есть задан `rotate`. `Div` может быть повернут на любой угол любой оси. Пользователь наводиться на этот блок и зажимает ЛКМ, после чего мышка выходит за область трансформации. В итоге получается линия. Первая точка - нажатие, вторая - пользователь отжал ЛКМ. Как можно перенести эту линию в систему координат блока? Это требуется для того, чтобы понять в каком направлении была проведена линия. Возможно, немного сумбурно, так что могу уточнить, если потребуется. Буду благодарен даже за направление, в котором нужно копать.

Upd:
Ещё раз повторюсь. Проблема в том, что если отслеживать нажатие мыши только на на 3d поверхности, то при выходе за её пределы события не произойдет. Следовательно, я должен отлавливать события документа или родительского блока, но они **уже не в 3d + у поверхности трансформация**, так что не понятно откуда и куда была проведена линия.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #content {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #eee;
    }
    
    #viewport {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
      -moz-perspective: 2000px;
      -ms-perspective: 2000px;
      perspective: 2000px;
      -webkit-perspective-origin: center -200px;
      -moz-perspective-origin: center -200px;
      -ms-perspective-origin: center -200px;
      perspective-origin: center -200px;
      background: #eee;
      border: 1px solid #aaa;
      margin: 200px auto;
    }
    
    #viewport .surface {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      border: 5px solid #f00;
      margin: 20px auto;
      transform: rotateX(43deg) rotateY(25deg);
      background: #575;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="viewport">
      <div class="surface"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    // events...
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: можно увидеть ваш код

Comment: @Избытоксусликов добавил код